# viewing big arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to understand an OO PHP application that landed on my desk. When I do a `print_r` or `var_dump` of a large array, I can get 18000+ lines.

Is there an on-line tool or class that can used to view and search the results better? For instance I have value named "company_name" which is three levels deep, it can take time to figure out a way to access it directly.

Comment: with out seeing the code kind of hard to answer.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to view/collapse branches like Notepad++ does with HTML XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up [Eclipse and XDebug](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930) and run the code through the debugger. But even without the debugger, you can set up just xdebug, and get enhanced outputs of var_dump.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Meaning to try eclipse. Setup & learning curve look steep. Does the payoff make it worth it?

Comment: @mortimer: absolutely. But even without Eclipse, you can use XDebug by itself, and it will automatically enhance all var_dumps. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to use print_r, but have line breaks to make reading the array easier...

create a new function with `<pre>` tags

```
function print_x($arr) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: even with this, I am finding it hard to trace heirarchy.

Comment: This breaks each key into it's own line, it doesn't get much better than that.  If the keys are index based you could always loop through and `print_x` each iterative value....

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/).

> To put it simply, Krumo is a replacement for print_r() and var_dump(). By definition Krumo is a debugging tool (initially for PHP4/PHP5, now for PHP5 only), which displays structured information about any PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick and dirty visual representation of the array with expandable/collapsible nodes I would just run it through `json_encode()` and user the browser's dev tools to take a peek at it.

Mind you there are *much* better ways to visualize the data (see other answers), but this one is the quickest with the tools at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very exact issue. I ended up finding a solution which turned the output into a collapsible tree.

Insert this function before `print_r` or `var_dump`.

```
<?php
function print_r_tree($data)
{
    // capture the output of print_r
    $out = print_r($data, true);

    // replace something like '[element] => <newline> (' with <a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('...');">...</a><div id="..." style="display: none;">
    $out = preg_replace('/([ \t]*)(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*\=\>[ \t]*[a-z0-9 \t_]+)\n[ \t]*\(/iUe',"'\\1<a href=\"javascript:toggleDisplay(\''.(\$id = substr(md5(rand().'\\0'), 0, 7)).'\');\">\\2</a><div id=\"'.\$id.'\" style=\"display: none;\">'", $out);

    // replace ')' on its own on a new line (surrounded by whitespace is ok) with '</div>
    $out = preg_replace('/^\s*\)\s*$/m', '</div>', $out);

    // print the javascript function toggleDisplay() and then the transformed output
    echo '<script language="Javascript">function toggleDisplay(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.display = (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block"; }</script>'."\n$out";
}
?>
```

Instead of `print_r()`, use `print_r_tree()`.

You may read more about the function and other answers I got on a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697756/how-do-i-theme-print-r-into-collapsible-rows).