# How do I theme print_r into collapsible rows?

Tags: php

Doing `print_r`, returns pages and pages of code; it's too hard to scroll pages to match children to parents, even wrapped with `<pre>` tags.

Is there a way to theme print_r into collapsible fields. Maybe an online generator, where I can post the contents of the `print_r($array);` and get a collapsible table of fields.

For example, in Drupal, there's a module, called [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), that does just that.
[image: Devel Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.print-r.php#90759), here's a solution.

Insert the following function, right before the `print_r`.

```
<?php
function print_r_tree($data)
{
    // capture the output of print_r
    $out = print_r($data, true);

    // replace something like '[element] => <newline> (' with <a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('...');">...</a><div id="..." style="display: none;">
    $out = preg_replace('/([ \t]*)(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*\=\>[ \t]*[a-z0-9 \t_]+)\n[ \t]*\(/iUe',"'\\1<a href=\"javascript:toggleDisplay(\''.(\$id = substr(md5(rand().'\\0'), 0, 7)).'\');\">\\2</a><div id=\"'.\$id.'\" style=\"display: none;\">'", $out);

    // replace ')' on its own on a new line (surrounded by whitespace is ok) with '</div>
    $out = preg_replace('/^\s*\)\s*$/m', '</div>', $out);

    // print the javascript function toggleDisplay() and then the transformed output
    echo '<script language="Javascript">function toggleDisplay(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.display = (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block"; }</script>'."\n$out";
}
?>
```

And then, substitute `print_r()`, with `print_r_tree()`; like this:

```
<pre><?php echo print_r_tree(get_defined_vars()); ?></pre>
```

Don't forget the `<pre>` tags.

The results look identical to that of `print_r()` function, except that now the arrays are collapsible.

Answer (score 10):

Unless I am missing something, the answer is in your screenshot: http://krumo.sourceforge.net/

**EDIT (2019):** Try https://github.com/kint-php/kint as it is still maintained today.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it won't require any additional libraries.

Comment: Xdebug can limit the nesting level of print_r output but doesn't do collapsing, so I think you will need a PHP library like this or something on the client side (eg. some Javascript that detects raw print_r output and converts it).

Comment: With all these CSS and JS beautifiers... can't believe something like that is not available online:/

Comment: @deizel `print_f` (or was it `vardump`) accepts a second parameter. It the parameter (loosely; `==`) evaluates to `true`, it returns a string containing the data. You could then parse that, but it could be very slow.

Answer (score 8):

Why not ouput it as JSON and then paste it on http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/, which makes it readible AND collapsible!

```
json_encode($array);
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: It works on some, but in my case is showing "Invalid JSON Variable". I'm assuming it's because of the html values within the array.

Comment: Or you gave it an object, not an array.

Comment: 2 years later... It really was an array. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the combination of the [original](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#90759) with [Christian's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874609/2133918), updated due to `preg_replace` deprecation (PHP 7):

```
function print_r_tree($data)
{
    // capture the output of print_r
    $out = print_r($data, true);

    // replace something like '[element] => <newline> (' with <a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('...');">...</a><div id="..." style="display: none;">
    $out = preg_replace_callback('/([ \t]*)(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*\=\>[ \t]*[a-z0-9 \t_]+)\n[ \t]*\(/iU', 'print_r_tree_callback', $out);

    // replace ')' on its own on a new line (surrounded by whitespace is ok) with '</div>
    $out = preg_replace('/^\s*\)\s*$/m', '</div>', $out);

    // print the javascript function toggleDisplay() and then the transformed output
    return '<script language="Javascript">function toggleDisplay(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.display = (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block"; }</script>'."\n$out";
}

function print_r_tree_callback($matches) {
    $id = substr(md5(rand().$matches[0]), 0, 7);
    return "$matches[1]<a href=\"javascript:toggleDisplay('$id');\">$matches[2]</a><div id='$id' style=\"display: none;\">";
}
```